# Сортировка в listview

Tags: delphi

Помогите, пожалуйста, отсортировать список в ListView по принципу сначала папки потом файлы. Вот код:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
WFD:WIN32_Find_Data;
HFile:THandle;
Attr,Path:String;
begin
 ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;{Начинаем прорисовку}
 ListView1.Items.Clear;
 Path:=IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter('C:\Windows'); //Добавляем '\' при его отсутствиии
 HFile:=FindFirstFile(PChar(Path+'*.*'),WFD); //Ищем файлы только в указанном каталоге
 if HFile<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then //Проверяем отсутствие ошиьок
  begin
   repeat
   if (WFD.dwFileAttributes and faHidden)<>2 then //Условие показыать\не показывать скрытые файлы
    if StrPas(WFD.cFileName)<>'.' then
     with ListView1.Items.Add do
      begin
       if (WFD.dwFileAttributes and faDirectory)<>faDirectory then
        begin
         Caption:=WFD.cFileName;
         SubItems.Add(ExtractFileExt(WFD.cFileName)); //Выделяем расширение
         SubItems.Add('размер'); //Размер файла
        end else
         begin
          Caption:=(WFD.cFileName); //Имя папки
          SubItems.Add('[Папка]'); //Указываем что это папка
          SubItems.Add('размер');
         end;
        SubItems.Add('Дата'); //Время создания папки\файла
        Attr:='----';
        if (WFD.dwFileAttributes and faArchive)<>0 then Attr[1]:='a'; //Архивный
        if (WFD.dwFileAttributes and faReadOnly)<>0 then Attr[2]:='r' //Только чтение
        if (WFD.dwFileAttributes and faHidden)<>0 then Attr[3]:='h'; //Скрытый
        if (WFD.dwFileAttributes and faSysFile)<>0 then Attr[4]:='s'; //Системный
        SubItems.Add(Attr); //Атрибуты файла\папки
      end;
      application.ProcessMessages;   // Чтобы форма не сильно тормозила во время поиска
   until FindNextFile(HFile,WFD)<>True;
   Winapi.Windows.FindClose(HFile);
  end;
  ListView1.Items.EndUpdate; //Заканчиваем прорисовку файлов
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сделать свою структуру, заполнить ее данными, с помощью `FindFirstFile`/`FindNexFile`. Затем отсортировать как нужно, и только потом выводить в `ListView`.

```
type
  TMyFileInfo = record
    Name: string;
    Extension: string;
    Size: UInt64;
    Attributes: string;
    // добавьте что вам там еще надо
  end;

var
  MyFiles: array of TMyFileInfo;
```

Заполняете массив `MyFiles`, затем сортируете, затем выводите.

Можно написать обработчик на событие `OnCompare` для `ListView`. Там сравнивайте записи `ListView` как вам угодно. Как сравните, так и отсортируются. Читайте справку как с этим работать.

В идеале нужно делать `ListView` виртуальным, делать свой список записей и там их сортировать.